# Prawn stroke_bounds in new pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I have this code for pdf generation using prawn in my rails project.

```
bounding_box([(bounds.left + 5), bounds.top - 130], width: 750) do    
        font_size(10)
        text "#{@post.description}", inline_format: :true, :overflow => :expand      
      end
```

The content of the text might be 2-3 pages. I want to create a border around the text. How can I do this?

I tried `transparent(0.5) { stroke_bounds }` But this only give single line. Again I can not use rectangle since the content is not fixed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bounding_box([(bounds.left + 5), bounds.top - 130], width: 750) do |t|   
  t.before_rendering_page do |page|
    stroke_bounds
  end
  font_size(10)
  text "#{@post.description}", inline_format: :true, :overflow => :expand      
end
```

It works for me. I hope it useful for you too. :)

Comment: This only works with tables, not bounding boxes [see manual](https://prawnpdf.org/prawn-table-manual.pdf#page=17)